# Is $n! \nmid n^n$ true for every sufficiently large $n$ (maybe $n \ge 3$)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

Is $n! \nmid n^n$ true for every sufficiently large $n$ (maybe $n \ge 3$)?

If so, how to prove it?

---

Note that it is easy to show that $n! \nmid n^n$ if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: how does it become easier when $n$ is prime I dont understand. ( I can see why it is easier when $n$ is odd)

Comment: "how does it become easier when n is prime I dont understand "  because $n^n$ has only one prime factor whereas $n!|n^n$ would imply *every* prime less then $n$ is a factor of $n$.  Such a concept should intuitively seem absurd.  And as Jorge Fernandez' excellent answer points out the prime factors of $n-1$ *can't* be factors of $n$.  So this is impossible.

Comment: The highest number this is posible is $2$ because $2$ is the only number in which there is only one prime equal or less than it and for this to be true *every* prime less than $n$ *including* those that divide $n-1$ must divide $n$.

Comment: oh ok, although its probably easier to see its impossible if $n$ is odd

Comment: @JorgeFernández $n! \nmid n^n \iff (n-1)! \nmid n^{n-1} \iff (n-1)! \neq n^i$ for some $i \le n-1$. If $n$ is a prime, then $n \nmid (n-1)! \implies (n-1)! \neq n^i$ for some $i$. Is this correct?

Comment: @hengxin that doesnt make a lot of sense in my opinion. I dont see how $(n-1)!\nmid n^ {n-1} \iff  (n-1)! \neq n^i$ for some $i\leq n-1$. That doesnt seem to be the normal definition of divisibility

Comment: @JorgeFernández I see. The "\Rightarrow" direction is not clear. Thanks. I made a mistake here.

Comment: @hengxin i am sorry, you are correct in the case when $n$ is prime, it is necessary, for $(n-1)!$ to be of that form as $n^ i$ are the only divisors of $n^ n$ . You are $100\%$ correct, my bad !

Comment: @JorgeFernández OK, I see. (That was my fault. I just forgot the assumption that $n$ is prime in writing that $\iff$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n!|n^ n$ then $n-1$ divides $n^n$.

$n$ and $n-1$ are coprime, it follows $n-1$ and $n^n$ are coprime, it follows $n-1$ does not divide $n^n$ unless $n-1=1$ which is not true as $n\geq 3$

Comment: I read this just after I posted my answer.. D'oh for simplicity.  +1

Comment: Wow, slick.....

Comment: @fleablood you can prove that $n^ n$ has at most $\log_3(n/2)+1$ distinct primes while it is also easy to prove $
\pi(2n)\ge \frac{n\log 2}{\log(2n)}
$ and this also allows you to finish

Comment: Well, I definitely know it was impossible as it would require $n$ be a multiple of *all* primes less than it.  Absurd.  It's just that I chose to use the relatively awkward Bertrands postulate to prove this obviously false idea was false.  And I completely overlooked the elegant and simple and ... well, obvious in hindsight... $\gcd(n-1, n) =1$.

Comment: Ok, thats nice. The proof of Bertrand uses ideas similar to the chebyshev bound though (at least the one by Erdos)

Answer (score 1):

Bertrands postulate.

If $p_k$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $n$ then there is a prime $p_{k+1}$ between $p_k < p_{k+1}< 2p_k - 2$.

But if $n!|n^n$ then the second largest prime $p_{k-1}$ is *also* a factor.  SO $n > p_{k-1}p_k > 2p_k -2 > p_{k+1}$.

So $p_{k+1}| n!$ but $p_{k+1}\not \mid n$.

A contradiction.

Comment: ... or as Jorge Fernandez points out.  $n-1$ must have prime factors that will not divide $n$ or $n^n$ but will divide $n!$.  So *much* simpler...